# BX Slider not working in Bigcartel site

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, bigcartel

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with using the BXSlider on a Big Cartel Theme Page. I have added the css to my style sheet and here is my code...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="https://code.google.com/p/bxslider/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
</script>

</head>
```

And what is in the body...

```
<div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;">
   <div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 220px;">

    <ul class="bxslider" style="width: auto; position: relative;">
    <li><img src='http://i1338.photobucket.com/albums/o690/robertalsogarrett/IMG_9821_zps67c74096.jpg'></li>
    <li> <img src='http://i1338.photobucket.com/albums/o690/robertalsogarrett/IMG_9907_zps2d37fd53.jpg'></li>
    <li><img src='http://i1338.photobucket.com/albums/o690/robertalsogarrett/IMG_9868_zpsa180b062.jpg' ></li>
  </ul></div>

  <div class="bx-controls bx-has-pager bx-has-controls-direction">
      <div class="bx-pager bx-default-pager">
         <div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="0" class="bx-pager-link active">1</a></div>
         <div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="1" class="bx-pager-link">2</a></div>
         <div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="2" class="bx-pager-link">3</a></div></div>
         <div class="bx-controls-direction"><a class="bx-prev" href="">Prev</a><a class="bx-next" href="">Next</a></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not actually including the bxslider script. You should download the source and serve it locally as recommend on the [bxslider site](http://bxslider.com/). In addition to this you are including two version of jQuery, not good.

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I don't know which version of bxslider you are using, but if it's possible you may want to consider the upgrading to the latest version.

Additional tip, the browsers built in developer tools will save you a lot of time. You should become very comfortable with them.

Here is an [example plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RD1ovZLmTtbLegTUYG4g?p=preview) that may help get you going.